# sql query condition

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

I've a table like this

```
days    discount    
  3      5.00   
  7     10.00   
10     15.00
```

Up to 3 day discount price is Rs 5. 4 to 7 price is Rs 10 and so on... I've total no of days.If no of days is < 4 then get 5.00 . if no of days 4 to 7 then get 10.How can I write condition in sql query

Comment: Is there another table involved? How do you the no of days?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`SELECT discount FROM mytable WHERE days > XXXX LIMIT 1` where XXX is the number of days you want.

Comment: I'd say you would need an equal sign if 3 days is a discount of 5, and 4 is a discount of 7.

Answer (score 2):

Take for instance '6' days. You want to select all discounts where the days in the table are bigger then your 6 (so 7 or 10), and then get the smallest (7).

```
SELECT discount FROM yourTable
WHERE
days >= '6'
ORDER BY days DESC
LIMIT 1
```

(As you said '3' has a discount too, I'm assuming that "4 to 7" means **including** 7. Otherwise, remove the `=` from the query)

As mentioned in the comments, you should use prepared statements if you can, so you would do something like this:

```
SELECT discount FROM yourTable
WHERE
days >= ?
ORDER BY days DESC
LIMIT 1
```

and then bind that ? to an integer.

Comment: +1 but using a prepared statement per nybbler's answer is good practice.

Comment: True, but the question was about an sql statement, not a complete database communication manual :). I can change the $ into a ? for completeness ofcourse :)

Answer (score 1):

You could create and use a prepared statement like the following:

```
SELECT discount 
FROM myTable 
WHERE days >= ?
ORDER BY days DESC 
LIMIT 1
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to use the [case construct](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/control-flow-functions.html) in your select statement.

```
SELECT CASE numdays 
    WHEN >= 8 THEN 15.0 
    WHEN >= 4 THEN 10.0 
    WHEN < 4 THEN 5.0
    END AS discount
```